# Pyodbc+Pandas how logic work? Cursor and DataFrame

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

want to take rows with Pyodbc and import them to DataFrame.
I want to see only DataFrame without printing rows at first.
If I try to delete 'print(something), IDE throws me an error because the 'If' cycle is not closed.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yts9.png]

````
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+databaseETL+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursorETL = cnxn.cursor()

cursorETL.execute("SELECT MAX(ID_load) FROM data.Sales_OffTake") 
for LastLoadConnector in cursorETL.fetchone():
    print(LastLoadConnector)
    
cursorETL.execute("SELECT FLOOR(SUM(Volume)) FROM data.Sales_OffTake") 
for SumVolumeConnector in cursorETL.fetchone():
    print(SumVolumeConnector)

cursorETL.execute("SELECT MAX(DateInvoice) FROM data.Sales_OffTake") 
for LastUpdateConnector in cursorETL.fetchone():
    print(LastUpdateConnector)

    Final = pd.DataFrame({'ETL': [LastLoadConnector, SumVolumeConnector, LastUpdateConnector]},
             index=['LastLoad')
    print(Final.to_markdown())```
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yts9.png]
````

Comment: To put it simply, the cursor object returns a generator when it fetches the results. The generator needs to be iterated to get its values. You could have `pass` instead of the print function, or wrap the cursor in a list() function and remove the for loops

Comment: Can type pls for example? 
I am starting work with it some days

Comment: If your query only returns a single value (one row, one column) then you can retrieve it with `cursorETL.execute(sql).fetchval()`